# Light blue background on a question in a question list

Tags: support, user-interface

I was browsing [asked questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and the question ["When should I use autoload instead of require?"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/364/when-should-i-use-autoload-instead-of-require) has a light blue background.

> [image]

What does this light blue background mean?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Conkeror or in Chrome.  Both on the browsing list and in the question itself.  Could you add a screenshot of it?

Comment: Here you are: http://www.zimagez.com/full/212a01d5ea6f47ca817defaa1cf6b754eb3861294b4e63779fbcd8c2d59f653ec39176df8f467080720b37a281f5edc1aa52d66f731c514c.php

Comment: Your link is dead. I added screenshot for you.

Comment: @nicael thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions that have a tag that you marked as favorite (a.k.a. interesting, different parts of the interface use different names) are shown with a colored background (light blue on this site) in question lists. That's pretty much all that “favorite tag” does.

See [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean/22185#22185) for a list of colors that appear on Stack Overflow and their significance. This site is in beta, so it uses different colors, but the principle is the same.

Comment: That explains my not being able to see the same effect.  And thank you for the link, it also explains colors I've seen in the past and wasn't sure of the meaning of.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot!